# DJI Windows SDK - media access

Tags: windows, dji-sdk

I plan to buy Mavic 2 Pro and use it with DJI Windows SDK.

My question is: **is it possible to access media stored on the Mavic 2 Pro through DJI Windows SDK**?

I know it is possible with DJI Mobile SDK (as it is also stated in features - "remote access to media stored on camera"). But I cannot find any info in DJI Windows SDK section about it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with the latest code hosted here https://github.com/dji-sdk/Windows-SDK
When I run this code and connect my Mavic 2 I can see all the media on the SDK Card.

So you should have no problem using the Windows SDK for this.